# Socket programing using python 2.7- socket.error: [Errno 10053]

Tags: python, sockets

Im trying to code client and a server which works on my computer.
The server should work until the client send him  "stop".
After sending to the server a request from the client, I close the server's socket but the client's socket is still open.
The client goes like this:

```
import socket


my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1729))

print "Enter the thing you want to do"
input2 = raw_input()

b = True

while b:

    my_socket.send(input2)

    data = my_socket.recv(1024)

    print data  # what I get

    print "Enter another thing you want to do"
    input2 = raw_input()

    if input2 == "stop":
        b = False

my_socket.send("stop")
data = my_socket.recv(1024)
my_socket.close()
```

In the first call, the Server sends what he need to send. 
However, if I ask the server to do another request, It show me the **socket.error: [Errno 10053]**
Why is that?

Comment: *WSAECONNABORTED 10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host computer, possibly due to a data transmission time-out or protocol error.*  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Are you sure the server is still running when you send the second message ?

Comment: Hmm... I do not know. I just send to the server a new request/